# modules_install hook causes constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {role_permission} (rid, permission, module)

Tags: hooks, users, features, installation

I am trying to set several permissions when a feature is being enabled (a new content type). 
By default this content type is disabled, and an admin can go to `structure/features` and enable it

under `docroot/profile/my_profile/features/foo` I created the following `foo.install` file

```
function foo_modules_installed($modules) {
 if (in_array('foo', $modules)) {
  $perms = array(
    'create foo content',
    'edit own foo content',
    ); 
      user_role_grant_permissions(user_role_load_by_name('publisher')->rid, $perms);
      user_role_grant_permissions(user_role_load_by_name('administrator')->rid, $perms);
}
}
```

but when I go to `structure/features` and enable it, I get the following error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {role_permission} (rid, permission, module
```

I tried different hooks, like enabled and so forth and all have the same issue.

How can I have a feature disabled by default, but still grant permissions to some users? What am I doing wrong

Comment: Read the comments on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_grant_permissions/7.x

Comment: which one? Cause someone claims he used it in hook_install and it worked

Comment: I vaguely remember this being a Features bug. I would check the issue queue for Features and search for this. It is hard to track down... if I recall, it seems like you're trying to add permissions for a module dependency that is not yet enabled. At the same time, you cannot have a module be disabled, but still execute code (especially install hook).

Comment: @Kevin, I am trying to have a feature that is disabled by default, and that will have permissions after it was enabled. 

I doubt I am the first person in the world, who needs a module to not be enabled by default, but still get permissions at some point during the process

Comment: There is some history here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1063204 - looks like for me, setting permissions in hook_enable worked over hook_install. YMMV.. probably worth digging through Features queue.

Comment: The drupal_static_reset patch is not working either

Comment: enable in .install is not causing the error, but also not setting any permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a `hook_install()` in the .install file for the feature will work if called with

```
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it seems to work for me